# Convert String to Map

Tags: groovy

```
def val = "[name: searchBaseDN value: , name: enable value: false, name: userDn value:  
cn=EAGREAD,ou=Users,ou=Administration,o=hyn, name: base value:  , name: prefsize value: 1,   
name: timeBetweenEvictionRuns value: 300000]"
```

I would like to convert it into hashmap val[name:value]

Thanks for your help .

Comment: is that an array or a String? If it is a String as the code indicates, then you will need to parse and extract that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks promising:

```
matches = val =~ /name:\s+(.*?)\s+value:\s+(.*?)(,\s+|\s+|])/

def newVal = [:]
matches.each { m ->
    newVal[m[1]] = m[2]
}
```

But if the string is changed slightly, the regex might break...

Comment: You could use inject as well: `def newVal = matches.inject( [:] ) { m, match ->  m << [ (match[1]): match[2] ] }`

Comment: if the val = "[ name: urls value: lp://23.165.3.215:383, lp://23.165.3.216:383, name: searchBaseDN value: ,] what change I need to do in the pattern . In the result only one url is showing .[urls
lp://23.165.3.215:383]

Comment: @tim_yates or even `def newVal = matches.collect { it[1, 2] }.collectEntries()` =D