# Convert String to Map without regex

Tags: java, string, kotlin, split, hashmap

I have a server that returns a String of this format:

```
{"success":true,
 "visible":false,
 "data":
     {"ref":"asfdasfsadfaeweatsagsdfsad",
      "userRef":"asdfsadfsa","accountType":"REAL",balance":43},
"code":"2200",
"msg":null,
"msgRef":null,
"successAndNotNull":true,
"failedOrNull":false,
"failed":false,
"failedAndNull":false}`
```

Then I extract the `data` by doing this:

```
val jsonObj : Any! = JSONObject(serverResponse.toString()).get("data").toString()
```

and I end up with this String:

```
"{"ref":"safdasfdwaer",
 "userRef":"fdgsgdsgdsfg",
 "accountType":"REAL",
 "balance":43}"
```

Is there an efficient way to extract the the values into a HashMap with key what is on the left of ":" and value what is on the right of ":"?

I have already seen the answer here ([Convert String to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691304/convert-string-to-map)) but I am not allowed to to use regex

Comment: Ive seen this thread. JSONObject(serverResponse.toString()).get("data") in Kotlin returns data type "Any!" which leaves me unable to use  new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, HashMap.class); because I dont actually have a JSON_SOURCE

Comment: @JanisLadja convert it to String then.

Comment: And then from String to JSON, or from String to Json to Map?

Comment: JSON_SOURCE is of type String, so you will pass your String to new `ObjectMapper().readValue(String, HashMap.class);` and get the map

Comment: @JanisLadja I proposed an answer where described thing in a detailed way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you force your `jsonObj` to be `Any` by writing type explicitly

```
val jsonObj : Any!
```

Since your method actually returns String (as it ends with `toString()`)

```
JSONObject(serverResponse.toString()).get("data").toString()
```

Just write

```
val jsonObjStr = JSONObject(serverResponse.toString()).get("data").toString()
```

And then use solution from the answer we proposed in the comments.

```
val result: Map<String, Any> =
   ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonObjStr, HashMap::class.java);
```

Comment: Why even go through the hoops of first using `JSONObject`, converting it back to a string, and then using `ObjectMapper`? Just use `ObjectMapper` directly.